# Is casting the class returned by getClass() of a generic instance type always safe in Java?

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-erasure

I am not sure how to word the title of this question in a concise way. There are a few related questions I have found, for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20method,are%20compiled%20into%20the%20class.&text=If%20you%20have%20code%20that,parameterized%20type%20is%20%22erased%22.), but none of them seem to answer the question I have explicitly.

But essentially what I am asking is this:

Consider the following code

```java
static <A, B> Class<? extends A> getLeftClass(Pair<A, B> tuple) {
   A left = tuple.getLeft();
   return left.getClass();
}
```

As is, this code does not compile. The compilation fails with the error
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#20-of ? extends Object> to Class<? extends A>`

I think this is essentially because `getClass` returns a type `Class<? extends Object>` but the compiler is expecting `Class<? extends A>`.

A solution is to cast the class as follows:

```java
static <A, B> Class<? extends A> getLeftClass(Pair<A, B> tuple) {
   A left = tuple.getLeft();
   return (Class<? extends A>) left.getClass();
}
```

This compiles. However, there is a warning because of an unchecked cast.

My question is, is the warning justified? Is there a legitimate reason not to do this? Or is this just a case where the compiler can't verify that it is correct, but it will always work as long as `tuple.getLeft()` is indeed an instance of `A`?

---

By the way, the `Pair` class is [this one](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html), from the Apache commons library

Comment: Your assumption looks right to me. I think it's a quirk of Java's generics that `x.getClass()` doesn't declare its return type as `Class<? extends X>` anyway; especially since the compiler sometimes treats it as though it does.

Comment: Try your original code with a return type of `Class<A>`.  I think `extends` is wrong.  If anything the class type should be a super class of A, not a sub class.

Comment: @markspace A variable of type `A` can hold an object at runtime of type `A` or any subtype of `A`. Hence `Class<? extends A>`.

Comment: @khelwood I don't think generics are covariant like that.  `A` is not a variable but a type parameter.  Its type can only be A.  (At least, without any constraints, I don't think `A` will ever resolve to anything but itself.)

Comment: @khelwood where would `X` be taken from, though? `getClass` is declared in `java.lang.Object`

Comment: @markspace If you have a `Pair<A,B>` then `left` is expected to be an instance of `A`. But an instance of `A` might be a direct instance of some subtype of `A`. So its class would be `? extends A`.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, that's why its declared return type is `Class<?>`; but its actual return type is `Class<? extends X>` where `X` is whatever the type is of the reference you're calling `getClass()` on.

Comment: @khelwood I suppose, you mean [this rule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2), "*The type of a method invocation expression of `getClass` is `Class<? extends |T|>`, where `T` is the class or interface that was searched for `getClass` (§15.12.1) and `|T|` denotes the erasure of `T` (§4.6).*" The erasure point might be annoying but as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64400761/2711488) demonstrates, dropping that rule would result in unsafe code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is justified, as it allows in turn other unsafe operations that would not cause a warning. The type parameter of `Class` allows you to perform dynamic runtime casts and instantiations and the type safety of those operations depends on the validity of the type parameter.

In other words, your method allows the following operation:

```java
Pair<List<String>,?> p = Pair.of(new ArrayList<>(), null);

List<Integer> listOfI = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
List<String> listOfS = getLeftClass(p).cast(listOfI);
listOfS.set(1, "foo");
```

This situation is called *heap pollution* and Java's generic type system guarantees that this situation can not occur with warning free source code. You get a warning and have the risk.

Likewise, we could do:

```java
List<String> stringList = getLeftClass(p)
    .getConstructor(Collection.class).newInstance(listOfI);
assert stringList.get(0) instanceof String;// will fail
```

There are similar 3rd party libraries, e.g. deserializers for XML or JSON, with similar assumptions about the type safety when being provided with a `Class` object as parameter to describe the assumed return type (or a component of the result).

Comment: thank you for proving me wrong. Now the problem is that `getLeftClass` is  a bit useless for the OP, isn't it?

Comment: @Eugene I encountered scenarios where I needed such unchecked casts on `Class` objects myself; the important point is to keep the cast and the subsequent use of the object in the same code unit, as close as possible, so that the reason and implications remain recognizable. A utility method that hides the cast would be counter-productive.